# MongoDB with Ruby driver how to create fields with curl?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, curl, terminal

I am sending the following curl request to my Ruby Driver

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstName" : "Frodo",  "lastName" : "Baggins" }' http://localhost:4567/new_document/?
```

This is the code for the POST operation in ruby.

```
post '/new_document/?' do
  content_type :json
  db = settings.mongo_db
  result = db.insert_one params
  db.find(:_id => result.inserted_id).to_a.first.to_json
end
```

I get the following response in the console.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 43
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2013-11-22)
Date: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 18:38:59 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"_id":{"$oid":"564239c3e89bde194d000007"}}
```

As you can see the fields first and last name never get created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! This creates the correct fields and their values.

```
curl -d 'name=adam&last=hoffman' http://localhost:4567/new_document/?
```